# Why Snowflake task is not able to insert data into a table which has TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9) column

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

**Problem Statement :**

I developed one stored procedure in Snowflake which has the logic inside as load data into a table from one view.

However, when this stored procedure is called from within a task, no data is getting inserted. This is happening only when there is TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9) data type column.

I am providing all code for table creation, insert view creation, stored procedure and task.

calling the stored procedure manually works fine. Calling this from within a task does not work. No error is also thrown in table(information_schema.task_history())

I checked with BOTH execute as OWNER and execute as CALLER. Nothing changes.

**Code Snippet**

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE TEST_DB.TEST_SCHEMA.TEST_DATE_VALUE

(
    NUMBER VARCHAR,
    TEST_DATE TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9)

)

create or replace view TEST_DB.TEST_SCHEMA.V_INSERT_TEST_DATE_VALUE(
    NUMBER,
    TEST_DATE 
) as
SELECT TOP 10 T0.NUMBER,T0.TEST_DATE 
FROM TEST_DB.TEST_SCHEMA.TEST_SOURCE_VIEW AS T0
WHERE T0.TEST_DATE is NOT NULL;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_DB.TEST_SCHEMA.SP_LOAD_TEST_DATE_VALUE("SRC_TABLE_NAME" VARCHAR(16777216))
RETURNS VARCHAR(16777216)
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS '  
var ret = -1;
var V_QUOTE_SRC_TABLE_NAME = "''" + SRC_TABLE_NAME +  "''";
var V_INSERT_VIEW_NAME = "V_INSERT_" + SRC_TABLE_NAME;
    if (1==1)
    {
        var V_INSERT = "INSERT INTO TEST_DB.TEST_SCHEMA." + SRC_TABLE_NAME + " SELECT * FROM TEST_DB.TEST_SCHEMA."+V_INSERT_VIEW_NAME ;
         var V_EXEC_INSERT = snowflake.createStatement( {sqlText: V_INSERT} );
         var V_RESULT_EXEC_INSERT = V_EXEC_INSERT.execute();
   return ret;
    }
    else
    return 100
    ;
  ';

call TEST_DB.TEST_SCHEMA.SP_LOAD_TEST_DATE_VALUE('TEST_DATE_VALUE');


create or replace task TEST_DB.TEST_SCHEMA.TASK_ESOPDASH_SP_LOAD_TEST_DATE_VALUE
    warehouse=W_ESOPDASH_DEVELOPER
    schedule='USING CRON 45 2 1 * * UTC'
    TIMESTAMP_INPUT_FORMAT='YYYY-MM-DD HH24'
    as call TEST_DB.TEST_SCHEMA.SP_LOAD_TEST_DATE_VALUE('TEST_DATE_VALUE');

EXECUTE TASK TASK_ESOPDASH_SP_LOAD_TEST_DATE_VALUE;
```

Date Values when the insertion happens by manual calling of the stored procedure

[image]

Comment: Can you temporarily change your SP to return the SQL statement that you are running (V_INSERT) and see what it contains when you run this via the task?

Comment: @Shruti Did you Alter task for its resumption. ALTER TASK TASK_NAME RESUME; Unless you resume this wouldn't kick off the procedure execution.

Answer (score 0):

Options might be:

1. task did not run - do you see that it ran in the TASK_HISTORY?
   1.1. If not, verify that you have permission to execute a TASK
   SHOW GRANTS TO ROLE <your_role_name>
   You should have EXECUTE TASK
2. tasks are started as suspended. Make sure you run: ALTER TASK TEST_DB.TEST_SCHEMA.TASK_ESOPDASH_SP_LOAD_TEST_DATE_VALUE RESUME
3. do you have permissions to run the WH W_ESOPDASH_DEVELOPER, is it the same that you use to run the SP manullay
4. You can do a small test like (I am not sure about the insert syntax for you)
   create or replace task t_dim_station_small
   warehouse = compute_wh
   schedule = '1 MINUTE'
   as
   INSERT INTO TEST_DB.TEST_SCHEMA.YOUR_TABLE_NAME (NUMBER, TEST_DATE)
   VALUES (123, '2024-02-08');

ALTER TASK t_dim_station_small RESUME

I hope something of these would help